# How can I assign a random integer with no overlap?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a seating plan generator for my class in Python. I have 4 list of strings: Yr 9 Girls, Yr 9 Boys, Yr 10 Girls and Yr 10 Boys. Then I was generating a pseudorandom integer and printing the results in a somewhat formatted result. These results would always overlap, how can I avoid this? I will be trying to implement some rules about the different groups which is why they are in 4 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the jumpahead to avoid overlapping

```
random.jumpahead(n)
```

or

```
random.sample(population, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> random.sample(["Jane","John","Jack","Jill"], 4)
['Jane', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jack']
>>> random.sample(["Jane","John","Jack","Jill"], 4)
['John', 'Jill', 'Jane', 'Jack']
>>> random.sample(["Jane","John","Jack","Jill"], 4)
['Jill', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jack']
>>> random.sample(["Jane","John","Jack","Jill"], 4)
['Jane', 'Jill', 'John', 'Jack']
>>> random.sample(["Jane","John","Jack","Jill"], 4)
['Jane', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jill']
```